# Cancel task that invoke 3rd party long running method

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I read some articles how to corectly cancel a task. Most of them describe: "you have to just add ThrowIfCancellationRequested() inside the method that is long running" - and that's it.

Ok - everything is clear but how to do it properly if we cannot modify method?
Please take a look on "DLL" class. I thought about to get current thread and abort it but that operation
is doesn't recommended by most of programmers. So my question is: how to do it properly?

Little example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LongRunningTask
{
    static class ClassWithAccess
    {
        public static void DoHeavyOperation(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Console.WriteLine("inside local method that we can modify");
            }
        }
    }

    static class DLL
    {
        public static void DoHeavyOperation()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                //ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); we can't do this
                Console.WriteLine("inside DLL");
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ct = src.Token;
            Console.WriteLine("start");

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //ClassWithAccess.DoHeavyOperation(ct);         
                DLL.DoHeavyOperation();
            }, ct);

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            src.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Cancel");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of 3rd party library are you using? Is it open sourced, Nuget, or security critical assembly? Also do you have any idea how complex is the code (based on the what does it do)?

Comment: If you are asking about it probably type of library has big impact and answer would be different according to the library that I use. I thought all DLLs that do not support cancellationToken can be treat the same(correct me if I am wrong). Let's consider two examples: 1. It's big sql query that returns data in JSON format 2. TCPScan method which is responsible for scanning device in the network and returns all information about device(which ports are open etc). Is it enough information for you?

Comment: if you don't have access to the 3rd party code and it does not support cancel then force kill might be your only bet